# GRID TO TXT in saga

Tags: export, saga

I have a problem in SAGA. I want to export several raster files to a .txt file. It means integration raster files to a .txt file. Can I do this in SAGA, if so how?

Answer (score 2):

In the menu use: modules\File\Grid\export\export grid to xyz